# Get API access token using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, oauth

I am writing a JS file which needs to access my Oauth2 API.  However, this will require an access token which requires data that I don't want others to be able to access for security so how can I make an ajax call to get the token to then use with other JS functions without exposing the key to any users of the website?

Comment: So in first time you wanna get your API Key for each user and then each user use the API key to do ajax request ? or you have a unique API Key and you don't want user to 'read' it ?

Comment: Since it is your API, you can very well restrict the domain from where the request is coming from. Why dont you do that?

Comment: @MaximeGirou I have an api secured using the Oauth2 methodology.  I also want to give a hosted JS file which uses this api to do particular actions.  with the API they can use it securely but the JS file will be readable completely from what I can see.

Comment: @Mani true, I could but wouldn't that be limited in security?  currently the api is oauth2

Comment: @Alan I guess what you want to achieve is the token is to be hidden but some how your API should be getting hold of it. let me take an example of Google maps. Google maps service is used by many websites and how can one show google maps on their site? It is by giving the user an end point and ask for a token that one should configure in their site. Since this token is available on their site, I can steal that token and use in my site. But Google maps don't allow that. How is what you may ask. That is by configuring the allowed hosts while generating that token.